# Load Automation Tool with Record option to test application in Linux OS

Tags: automated-testing, tools, test-automation-framework, browser-automation, load-testing

I am new to Linux. currently am using Ubuntu 12.04 ATS OS.
Request experts to help me selecting tool to use for Load Testing with Record and Play back option available. Would like to use an open source tool.
My team will definitely love if it's UI based.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Install Google chrome.
2. Install Blazemeter extension in chrome.
3. Download JMeter and set it up. Lots of tutorials available for that.
4. Record scripts with blazemeter and download them.
5. Run the scripts in JMeter.

Tada...

Comment: Successfully worked in windows having some plugin issues in ubuntu 12.04 chrome browser

Comment: Can you give more i formation about the problem you are facing in ubantu

Comment: Thank you it successfully worked in windows with 50 virtual users. Is there any way or other convenient load tool where i can have many more virtual users like thousands.

Comment: With jmeter you can generate load of about 100 - 200 users from a single machine. You can also do distributed testing with several machines.

Comment: There are other tools, but they are paid tools. Like Silk Performer and Loadrunner